# Prepros - C:bignum to big to convert into `long'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, bignum, prepros

I launch the Prepros application to compile scss in css.
But this error appear :

```
RangeError on line ["87"] of C: bignum too big to convert into `long'
Run with --trace to see the full backtrace

C:\Users\me\Desktop\FFF-Bootstrap\scss\style.scss
```

How to resolve it ?

Thank's

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are using a spritesheet? If so I believe the issue is with "chunkypng" when it cannot compile correctly.

I had this issue and resolved it by resaving all my pngs in photoshop. I guess there must have been an error in an image somewhere.